# Issue in mongo query with multiple conditions by using golang

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, go, mgo

I have a document as follows -

```
{ 
    "_id" : "580eef0e4dcc220df897a9cb", 
    "brandId" : 15, 
    "category" : "air_conditioner", 
    "properties" : [
        {
            "propertyName" : "A123", 
            "propertyValue" : "A123 678"
        }, 
        {
            "propertyName" : "B123", 
            "propertyValue" : "B123 678"
        }, 
        {
            "propertyName" : "C123", 
            "propertyValue" : "C123 678"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this, the `properties` array can have multiple number of elements.
When I perform a search via my API,
I would ideally pass an array similar to `properties` in the body of my `POST` request -

```
{ 
    "brandId" : 15, 
    "category" : "air_conditioner", 
    "properties" : [
        {
            "propertyName" : "A123", 
            "propertyValue" : "A123 678"
        }, 
        {
            "propertyName" : "B123", 
            "propertyValue" : "B123 678"
        }, 
        {
            "propertyName" : "C123", 
            "propertyValue" : "C123 678"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a struct to receive and decode this information -

```
type Properties struct {
    PropertyName  string `json:"propertyName" bson:"propertyName"`
    PropertyValue string `json:"propertyValue" bson:"propertyValue"`
}

type ReqInfo struct {
    BrandID      int             `json:"brandId" bson:"brandId"`
    Category     string          `json:"category" bson:"category"`
    Properties   []Properties    `json:"properties" bson:"properties"`
}
```

I can also perform a mongodb `$and` operation over the various `properties` and only when all of them match, the document is returned.
The problem here is that the number of elements in the `properties` array is not fixed.
I need to be able to send just

```
{ 
    "brandId" : 15, 
    "category" : "air_conditioner", 
    "properties" : [
        {
            "propertyName" : "A123", 
            "propertyValue" : "A123 678"
        }
    ]
}
```

and retrieve all the matching documents (not just one).

I tried my hand at creating a variable size `bson.M` using a for loop depending on the size of the `properties` array being received as the input but couldn't get the right way to do it!

How should this be approached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by constructing the `$and` part separately -

```
var AndQuery []map[string]interface{}
for i := 0; i < len(body.Properties); i++ {
    log.Println(body.Properties[i])
    currentCondition := bson.M{"properties": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"propertyName": body.Properties[i].PropertyName, "propertyValue": body.Properties[i].PropertyValue}}}
    AndQuery = append(AndQuery, currentCondition)
}
```

and then my query looked like -

```
c.Find(bson.M{"brandId": body.BrandID, "category": body.Category, "$and": AndQuery})
```